# How to style parent element if child element is empty?

Tags: html, css

Is there a way to style a parent element if the child element is empty? For example:

Here, the `<li>` element *is* empty so I'd like the `ul` element to be styled with `padding: 20px`:

```
<ul class="list">
    <li></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: a) there's no parent selector in CSS and b) CSS can't read the content of your elements. So no, you'd need JavaScript.

Comment: @henrywright - you'd only be able to check if the `li` contained no child elements: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:empty

Comment: Close voter please tell me where in my question it is unclear what I'm asking

Comment: ah it's unclear about the `<li>` You don't even say if your `ul` has only 1 `li` or it has some `li`s? if it has some `li`s so which `li` is empty to be the condition to style your `ul` or any `li`?

Comment: @KingKing thanks for your comment. There is a single `<li>` element.

Comment: if there is only 1 `li`, you may have a workaround such as instead of setting the padding of your `ul`, why not setting the `margin` of your `li`? that way you can use the `:empty` selector like this `li:empty { margin:20px;}`. Of course traversing back to your `ul` to set its `padding` to `20px` is impossible in CSS3 (maybe it's possible in CSS4).

Comment: @KingKing true about the workaround. But I've opted for a jQuery solution (see the accepted answer) because this will cover future situations where there may be more than a single `li`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a CSS parent selector?](/q/1014861/90527)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You can't target a parent element with CSS**. So it seems impossible to achieve this only with CSS.

Assuming you're using jQuery :

```
$('.list li:first-child').is(':empty').parent().css({"padding-top", "20px"});
```